# Event not showing up in the Property Grid

Tags: c#, events, propertygrid, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a special search text box. Among other things it have these two events:

```
    [Category("Behavior")]
    public event EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<string>> Search;

    [Category("Property Changed")]
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ActiveColorChanged;

    [Category("Property Changed")]
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> InactiveColorChanged;
```

Thing is that only the bottom two shows up in the design view property event explorer thingy (whatever it's name is...). And I am wondering why. Is it because I am not using the standard `EventArgs`? That shouldn't be the case though, cause I mean, there are other events not using that... like the key press related events, etc...

The `GenericEventArgs<T>` class looks like this:

```
public class GenericEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public GenericEventArgs() : this(default(T)) { }
    public GenericEventArgs(T value) { Value = value; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: BTW, your question will be easier for others to find if you edit your subject to use "Property Grid" instead of "design view property explorer thing". ;-)

Comment: someone has changed it to Properties Window. I wanted to use a better name but couldn't remember what it was called, so I left it to someone who knew :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the ***Property Grid*** does not support your double-generic EventHandler class. Try this:

```
public delegate void GenericHandler<T>(object sender, GenericEventArgs<T> e);
```

If that doesn't work, try a completely non-generic handler, if only to see if that's where the problem is.

If this *is* the problem, then I suggest you create a bug report about it on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/), then post the URL to the bug here so we can vote on it.

Comment: Um... how do I use this? for an event? public event GenericHandler<string> Search; ?

Comment: Seems like it did yes :D Thank you!

Comment: Actually... There seems to be something more going on here... the event shows up now, but when I double click it, i get the name searchTextBox_Search in the box, but it jump sto nowhere. If I double-click it again, I go to the method, but it looks like this: private void searchTextBox_Search(object sender). In other words, the event args part is missing =/ When I write searchTextBox.Search += and then press TAB, then I get a method with the correct signature... what is going on here...

Comment: And of course, it wont compile until I have fixed the signature of that method to what it should be... so the signature of the original delegate and event is correct.